# Change all first values in column, grouped from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have 2 columns - _a, _b.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'_a':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3],'_b':[3,4,5,3,3,3,9]})
df

    _a  _b
0   1   3
1   1   4
2   1   5
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   3   3
6   3   9
```

I need change first value in column _b to 0, grouped by column _a
Like here:

```
    _a  _b
0   1   0
1   1   4
2   1   5
3   2   0
4   2   3
5   3   0
6   3   9
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get indices of first occurrences for each value in `df._b` with `np.unique`:

```
df._b[np.unique(df._a, return_index=True)[1]] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.

Comment: For the record, I think @user2285236 has a better pandas solution.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `pd.Series.duplicated` returns False for the first item. Making use of this, you can do:

```
df.loc[~df['_a'].duplicated(), '_b'] = 0

df
Out: 
   _a  _b
0   1   0
1   1   4
2   1   5
3   2   0
4   2   3
5   3   0
6   3   9
```

Comment: I need change not dublicate. I need change first value in column _b to 0, grouped by column _a

Comment: Aren't they the same thing? If you group by _a, it means you are putting duplicated values of _a in the same group?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I understand. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

If the first values of each group aren't duplicates, you can use this:

`df.loc[df.groupby('_a').head(1).index, '_b'] = 0`

output:

```
        _a  _b
    0   1   0
    1   1   4
    2   1   5
    3   2   0
    4   2   3
    5   3   0
    6   3   9
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need.